# hadoop on cloud latency impact

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, hadoop

I'm a big data architect with no skills with the cloud.

I have always worked with Hadoop onPremise, I know that servers locality is a very serious concern as it may apply higher latency.

Today with Hadoop integration on the cloud I'm wondering :

1. If cloud providers ( AWS, AZURE ... ) have the possibility to
   offer hosts of the same cluster on the same locality to reduce the latency?
2. How do we manage the latency to transfer huge data from local
   machines to the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer, some cloud provider allow to have VMs on the same geographically zone ( as instance azure offer the possibility to choose availability zones ).

Answer (score -2):

I think that this should be on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said, I can still try to help!

- These cloud providers have ways to choose which regions your systems are hosted within. They are not "on-premises" since they are in a remote data center, but if you are running them in the same region then the latency between them will be surprisingly faster than you may expect. These companies work especially hard (at least, with AWS) to make it so that even when data isn't in the same region - it is still extremely fast to send and receive messages between even different countries while staying within their network. Many people will create VPNs inside of AWS for the sole purpose of being able to use their networks because they are extremely and most surprisingly low-latency.
- Generally, you don't have to worry about latency outside of your software's processing latency. That's one of the benefits of using a cloud provider.